# Detectar si la letra es consonante o vocal mediante strcmp

Tags: c, string

Soy nueva programando y no comprendo bien como funciona `strcmp`.

El ejercicio consiste en que tengo hacer un programa donde se introduzca una letra, y se imprima si el dato introducido es una consonante o una vocal.

Traté de hacerlo declarando los char pero no me sale

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
int strcmp (const char *cadena1, const char *cadena2);
const char cadena1;
const char cadena2;
char let;
char a,e,i,o,u;
      printf("Por favor, introduzca una letra \n");
       scanf("%c",&let);
 if (let == a,e,i,o,u)
  {
      printf("La letra introducida es una vocal\n");
  }
  else (let != a,e,i,o,u)
  {
    printf("la letra introducida es una consonante \n");
  }

printf("Fin del programa");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Como has podido comprobar esto no va a funcionar en la vida:

```
if (let == a,e,i,o,u)
```

Y es por dos motivos básicos:

1. `a`, tal cual está en el código, se tratará como si fuese **una variable**. Para que se considere un caracter debe ir con comillas simples: `'a'`
2. C no entiende de rangos ni de colecciones, la operación de comparación `==` solo compara dos valores entre sí... para saber si `let` pertenece a un conjunto de valores tienes que hacer todas las comprobaciones de forma manual:

   ```
   if( let == 'a' || let == 'e' || /* ... */ )
   ```

Adicionalmente, un poco de teoría de conjuntos. Dos conjuntos son disjuntos si ningún elemento del grupo A se encuentra en el grupo B, es decir si tienes una bolsa con bolas rojas y negras y sacas una bola, la misma o es roja o es negra... no puede ser mitad roja y mitad negra.

¿Y esto a qué viene?

Pues básicamente que si en el `if` compruebas si el caracter es una vocal, no es necesario comprobar justo lo contrario en el `else`... es totalmente redundante:

```
if( let == 'a' || let == 'e' || /* ... */ )
{
  // ...
}
else /* sin condiciones */
{
  // ...
}
```